# С++ fstream. Аспекты записи в .exe мнемоник

Tags: файлы, c++

Здравствуйте, пришло в голову написать свой простой компилятор для `asm`, нашел список мнемоник для своей архитектуры в восьмеричном формате. Меня интересуют аспекты записи в `.exe` файл этих мнемоник, желательно дать ссылку на соответствующую статью, ибо как оказалось я не могу манипулировать файлами отличными от `.txt` формата.

Comment: А кто Вам мешает манипулировать файлами, отличными от txt?

Comment: Например я создал png файл попробывал записывать туда число, после этого этот файл открывался с ошибкой, так же и с exe

Comment: А как Вы его открываете? (Я не телепат). Две типичные ошибки. Не указан режим двоичных чтения-записи(1). В имени файла, точнее в пути к нему, неправильно указаны обратные слеши(2). Обе ошибки из dos/windows.

      fstream filestr ("C:\\test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::binary);

А вот что значит "создал png, записывал туда число" -- тут, пожалуйста, поподробнее.

Comment: открываю его fstream input("input.png"); Записываю так же

Comment: ifstream in("in.png");
ofstream out("out.png");
out<<0xFFFFFF;

Comment: И что в результате должно получиться? У png свой формат. И что там могут значить 0xFFFFFF, я понятия не имею. Если нужно поверх рисунка нанести число, то это должно делаться как-то иначе. (про режим binary я уже написал)

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch27s02.html - оба курите.

Comment: Ссылка хороша, но лучше было бы пересказать ее своими словами.

Comment: @gecube ну с английского-то я как нибудь со словарём переведу. А вот я языка o2n3e кто переведёт? Вы?

Comment: если ты записывал число в PNG файл, а не изображение, то естественно он будет выдавать ошибку. Это всё тот же текстовый файл с цифрой, но с расширением PNG